# set an alarm to any date and time from datepicker dialog

Tags: android

I try to use datepicker to set the time, and I also built an alarm for that time I set, but the alarm always paly at current time instead of my set time, I don't know why, please help, thanks!  here is my code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove this line:

```
alarmTime.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

as it set the time of the calendar to current time.